# Error with python JSON module to read a JSON file

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, file

I tried to read a meta data (from http://jmcauley.ucsd.edu/data/amazon/links.html) in json format. 
It has the following error.
Is there anyone could help me?

```
text-classification-python-master xupin$ python data_prep.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data_prep.py", line 79, in <module>
    content = json.load(open('dumps/all_products.json'), encoding='utf8')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 291, in load
    **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 352, in loads
    return cls(encoding=encoding, **kw).decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Comment: Typically this error is caused by some arbitrary text being present in the input stream that you are feeding to json.load(s). So to investigate make sure that the contents of the file only have well-structured json. Try adding a read() and use json.loads().

Comment: also, please add your code so we can see what you are attempting to do

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead:

```
with open('dumps/all_products.json', 'r') as fd:
    content = json.loads(fd.read())
```